# Apache Active Directory mod_authnz_ldap not working

Tags: apache, active-directory, ldap, httpd.conf

I have been trying to get AD auth on a virtualhost page working for the past several days, to no avail. Help...

CentOS 7

Apache 2.4.6

mod_ldap and mod_authnz_ldap installed and loading

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wwwtest/public
    ServerName wwwtest.example.com
    ErrorLog logs/wwwtest.example.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/wwwtest.example.com-access_log common
    <Directory /var/www/wwwtest/public>
        Allow from all
        Order Allow,Deny
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "login"
        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        AuthLDAPBindDN ldapuser@EXAMPLE.COM
        AuthLDAPBindPassword ldappassword
        AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ldap01.example.com:3268/ou=employees,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=user)"
        AuthLDAPBindAuthoritative off
        Require valid-user
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have trace8 enabled in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

And this is what I see in /var/log/httpd/wwwtest.example.com-error.log

```
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.213178 2015] [http:trace4] [pid 20648] http_request.c(301): [client 172.16.250.250:49559] Headers received from client:
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.213263 2015] [http:trace4] [pid 20648] http_request.c(305): [client 172.16.250.250:49559]   Host: wwwtest.example.com
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.213278 2015] [http:trace4] [pid 20648] http_request.c(305): [client 172.16.250.250:49559]   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.213284 2015] [http:trace4] [pid 20648] http_request.c(305): [client 172.16.250.250:49559]   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.213289 2015] [http:trace4] [pid 20648] http_request.c(305): [client 172.16.250.250:49559]   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.213293 2015] [http:trace4] [pid 20648] http_request.c(305): [client 172.16.250.250:49559]   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.213297 2015] [http:trace4] [pid 20648] http_request.c(305): [client 172.16.250.250:49559]   DNT: 1
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.213301 2015] [http:trace4] [pid 20648] http_request.c(305): [client 172.16.250.250:49559]   Connection: keep-alive
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.213305 2015] [http:trace4] [pid 20648] http_request.c(305): [client 172.16.250.250:49559]   Cache-Control: max-age=0
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.213309 2015] [http:trace4] [pid 20648] http_request.c(305): [client 172.16.250.250:49559]   Authorization: Basic RTAxMDEwMTAxOkNvbmNvcmRpYTIwMTU=
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.213530 2015] [authz_core:debug] [pid 20648] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 172.16.250.250:49559] AH01626: authorization result of Require valid-user : denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.213556 2015] [authz_core:debug] [pid 20648] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 172.16.250.250:49559] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.213644 2015] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 20648] mod_authnz_ldap.c(501): [client 172.16.250.250:49559] AH01691: auth_ldap authenticate: using URL ldap://ldap01.example.com:3268/ou=employees,ou=users,dc=example,dc=edu?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=user)
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.213705 2015] [authnz_ldap:trace1] [pid 20648] mod_authnz_ldap.c(522): [client 172.16.250.250:49559] auth_ldap authenticate: final authn filter is (&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=TESTUSER))
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.215123 2015] [ldap:debug] [pid 20648] util_ldap.c(372): AH01278: LDAP: Setting referrals to On.
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.216479 2015] [ldap:trace2] [pid 20648] util_ldap.c(591): [client 172.16.250.250:49559] ldap_simple_bind() failed with server down (try 1)
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.217336 2015] [ldap:trace2] [pid 20648] util_ldap.c(591): [client 172.16.250.250:49559] ldap_simple_bind() failed with server down (try 2)
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.217358 2015] [ldap:trace2] [pid 20648] util_ldap.c(606): [client 172.16.250.250:49559] attempt to re-init the connection
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.217398 2015] [ldap:debug] [pid 20648] util_ldap.c(372): AH01278: LDAP: Setting referrals to On.
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.218332 2015] [ldap:trace2] [pid 20648] util_ldap.c(591): [client 172.16.250.250:49559] ldap_simple_bind() failed with server down (try 3)
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.219355 2015] [ldap:trace2] [pid 20648] util_ldap.c(591): [client 172.16.250.250:49559] ldap_simple_bind() failed with server down (try 4)
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.219392 2015] [ldap:trace2] [pid 20648] util_ldap.c(606): [client 172.16.250.250:49559] attempt to re-init the connection
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.219430 2015] [ldap:debug] [pid 20648] util_ldap.c(372): AH01278: LDAP: Setting referrals to On.
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.219444 2015] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 20648] mod_authnz_ldap.c(539): [client 172.16.250.250:49559] AH01694: auth_ldap authenticate: user TESTUSER authentication failed; URI / [LDAP: ldap_simple_bind() failed][Can't contact LDAP server] (not authoritative)
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.219454 2015] [auth_basic:error] [pid 20648] [client 172.16.250.250:49559] AH01618: user TESTUSER not found: /
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.219469 2015] [core:trace3] [pid 20648] request.c(119): [client 172.16.250.250:49559] auth phase 'check user' gave status 401: /
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.219530 2015] [http:trace3] [pid 20648] http_filters.c(992): [client 172.16.250.250:49559] Response sent with status 401, headers:
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.219532 2015] [http:trace5] [pid 20648] http_filters.c(999): [client 172.16.250.250:49559]   Date: Wed, 21 Oct 2015 19:12:56 GMT
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.219534 2015] [http:trace5] [pid 20648] http_filters.c(1002): [client 172.16.250.250:49559]   Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.219536 2015] [http:trace4] [pid 20648] http_filters.c(835): [client 172.16.250.250:49559]   WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\\”login\\”
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.219538 2015] [http:trace4] [pid 20648] http_filters.c(835): [client 172.16.250.250:49559]   Content-Length: 381
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.219540 2015] [http:trace4] [pid 20648] http_filters.c(835): [client 172.16.250.250:49559]   Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.219541 2015] [http:trace4] [pid 20648] http_filters.c(835): [client 172.16.250.250:49559]   Connection: Keep-Alive
[Wed Oct 21 12:12:56.219542 2015] [http:trace4] [pid 20648] http_filters.c(835): [client 172.16.250.250:49559]   Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

I can do ldapsearch with these credentials and it returns user objects from our DC, so the credentials are correct. I ran Wireshark on the DC. It never saw any LDAP packets from this web server. I ran tcpdump on the web server and it never sent any LDAP packets when I attempted to auth...

We got AD auth via PHP working in like 10 minutes, but I had previously been working on this for days...so sure, it auth works now, but I want to know why mod_ldap and mod_authnz_ldap aren't working...or...what isn't working.

Also, I'm kinda new with Apache...so the problem is more than likely something I'm misunderstanding.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**: Apparently it works just fine in Debian. (Apache 2.2.22, bu still) ***sigh***

Comment: @Jongware done. sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SOLVED**: Clearly I'm still new at Linux as well.

It was, of course, an issue with SELinux. Even though I had set it from Enforcing to Permissive (and then eventually to Disabled), I didn't know that the only way to make that change is apparently by rebooting (or, setenforce 0). Rebooted, and it all worked fine because SELinux was now disabled. I then found that SELinux logs are at /var/log/audit/audit.log. There, were a bunch of:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1445466425.176:1849): avc:  denied  { name_connect } for  pid=21184 comm="httpd" dest=389 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:ldap_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket
```

So to allow httpd to access ldap, I followed [this post](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/ldap-authentication-error-%5Bcan't-contact-ldap-server%5D-from-apache-httpd-920907/#post4560369) which says:

```
# getsebool -a | grep ldap
authlogin_nsswitch_use_ldap --> off
httpd_can_connect_ldap --> off

# setsebool httpd_can_connect_ldap 1

# getsebool -a | grep ldap
authlogin_nsswitch_use_ldap --> off
httpd_can_connect_ldap --> on
```

After that, auth worked perfectly with Firewalld enabled and with SELinux Enforcing. That also explains why a tcpdump showed no ldap bind attempts.

So yeah, hopefully this helps out anyone else that may have been stuck.

Bottom line: learn more about SELinux.